# Space after anchored image in textframe InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, spacing

I am wanting to create 10 pt spacing before and after the dashed line. I created 10pt space after the items and pricing but am not sure how to create space after the dashed line? As you can see I've turned hidden characters on and there is a line break just below the dashed line which has created spacing but I am wanting to alter that spacing.

[image]

UPDATE:
I have done a test using text with no character or paragraph styles applied. This is what it looks like with no space before/after applied.
[image]

[image]

When I add space before and after it seems to work either way. I don't really know whether there were overriding settings on paragraph styles but in this case it maybe easier to just use a rule.

Comment: Hard to say without access to your document. You could have manually *moved* the line upwards? Try cutting it and pasting it back. Or the paragraph it's anchored in have *baseline shift*? Or the line is in a *group* with a transparent frame? Or the line has a *Y Offset* added in its *Anchored Object Options*?

Comment: Are you using paragraph rules or pasting the rule as an inline graphic? I wouldn't paste the rule as an inline graphic, I'd use Paragraph rules - allowing for paragraph styles to easily add rules when necessary. Using paragraph rules, it's a combination of the `Offset` for the rule in conjunction with space after for the preceding paragraph for a rule below. And `Offset` and leading or space before for the paragraph if using a rule before.

Comment: @Scott, yes, in this case a paragraph rule would be better, but the title *does* mention "anchored image". A line could also be styled in a way not possible with paragraph rules.

Comment: *"A line could also be styled in a way not possible with paragraph rules."* -- very true `:)`

Comment: Yes I think I should use a rule it seems to make more sense

Comment: Doesn't answer the question though ...